# JDBC program to invoke stored procedure with complex inputs and output

Tags: java, jdbc

Can you please help me writing the JDBC program to call the below stored procedure which is having the complex input type.

Below is my stored procedure definition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE inputObjects_t AS OBJECT (
    serviceID        VARCHAR2(7),
    offerID          VARCHAR2(7),
    transactionID    NUMBER
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE inputArray_t IS VARRAY(100) OF inputObjects_t

PROCEDURE CheckObjectInput( pCustomerRef IN VARCHAR2,
                                 pSubscriptionPS IN NUMBER,
                                 pExpiryObjects IN inputArray_t,
                                 pTransactionDtm IN DATE,
                                 pTransactionID IN NUMBER);

PROCEDURE CheckObjectOutput( pCustomerRef IN VARCHAR2,
                                 pSubscriptionPS IN NUMBER,
                                 pExpiryObjects OUT inputArray_t,
                                 pTransactionDtm IN DATE,
                                 pTransactionID IN NUMBER);
```

Comment: You might want to mention what database the stored procedure is running against.  JDBC processes are pretty much the same, connect to the database, process SQL, commit, disconnect from the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Oracle, please use the class `OracleCallableStatement`.
There's a method called `setSTRUCT`.

Generical Example:

```
OracleConnection conn = (...)
OracleCallableStatement cs = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(sql);
StructDescriptor sd = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("MY_TYPENAME", conn);
Object[] attribs = new Datum[3];
attribs[0] = new CHAR("value1",  charSet);
attribs[1] = new CHAR("value2",  charSet);
CLOB clob2 = attribs[2] = new CLOB(conn);
STRUCT st = new STRUCT(sd, conn, attribs);
(...)
cs.setSTRUCT(n, st);
(...)
cs.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want a pool to store you database connections and then methods to call the stored procs. You'll probably want something like:

```
public callStoredProc(String serviceID, String offerID, Integer trasnactionID) {
   try {
   myConnection.startTransaction();
   StringBuilder mySQL = new StringBuilder();
   ... build sql statement ...
   myConnection.execute(mySQL.toString());
   } catch (SQLException sqle) {
   ...
   } finally {
      myConnection.endTransaction();
      ... sql cleanup ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Michael & Gilbert I did't understood can you please give me more details.

Comment: You need to manage your database connections so you create a pool (not shown in this answer). For lengthy sql stored procedures you want to start a transaction in case they fail, form the sql request and perform it. Since SQL connections can fail and the database can throw errors you need a series of catch statements followed by a finally statement to cleanup your connection. In my case the stored procs could only be run once so I wrapped the call in a semaphore to make sure that it wasn't called twice.